# Leaky basement against wall under back yard deck

Tags: basement, leak

I have a small leak in the basement. Isolated to one corner really, it worsens after rainy days but it seems to be leaky even when it doesn’t rain. This area is under a deck. What are my options here? Am I supposed to remove the deck and fix the sloping to away from the foundation?

Thank you.

Comment: Please add a photo

Comment: Leaky foundations should be fixed from the outside and usually involves digging.  Fixing slope and making sure extra water(from roof) is carried away might be enough.  Removing the deck might only be required if you use machines(use hands).

Comment: If it's leaking when it's not raining, you may have a fairly high water table.  Only a perimeter drain will help you in that situation.